# Word to describe plants that are negatively affected by being smothered by other plants

Tags: plant-physiology

Used in the sentence:

> There was no garden when they moved in, so they are not *(???)* any existing plants.

I wanted to say *threatening*, but I am curious if a word specifically relating to this phenomenon.

Comment: The logic underlying this sentence a bit troubling in that it posits *replacement* of a *pre-existing* garden as the locus of a threat to plant life. Is there some way to reword it that is less tautological?

Comment: *[Crowding out](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crowd%20out)* is idomatic here.

Comment: @DJohnson good point. Perhaps I should phrase it as `...they are not (???) any preexisting plants.`

Answer (score 2):

How about “competing”? As in, “They are not competing with any existing plants.”

The word “competition” comes up quite frequently in the study of biology and ecology when describing the interactions between two or more species, hence my suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

"threatening" is good, or as lightweaver said "competing with", 
crowding, hindering, affecting, incompatible with, shading.

i assume you are introducing new plants to an existing space